# AngularUI Datepicker Entering Different Year Format

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui

I am using an older version of AngularUI (version 0.13.4 - 2015-09-03) with Datepicker.  I have the popup date set to use 'MM/dd/yyyy'.  The problem, if a user does not use the popup datepicker and types in 10/18/2016, it works fine.  If the user types in 10/18/16, it does not recognize it as a date.  I've tried using some custom validation below, but I can't get it to work with the datepicker.  If I remove "datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyy" from the input the validation works, but of course, the datepicker no longer works.  I cannot get the datepicker and the validation to work together.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ng-form name="form">
<p class="input-group">
    <span style="float:left">
        <input name="dteAnswer" style="width:200px; height:30px" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" ng-pattern='/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(199\d)|([2-9]\d{3})$/' ng-model="q.dteDateAnswer" type="text" is-open="status.opened" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy">
    </span>
    <span ng-show="form.dteAnswer.$error.pattern">Incorrect Format, should be MM/DD/YYYY</span>
    <span style="float:left" class="input-group-btn"><button style="height:30px" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button></span>
</p>
</ng-form>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try `MM/dd/y' ? .. from the documentation 
_y (Example: 15) - Parses a year with 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits._ https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Okay, well, this is weird.  Putting MM/dd/y in datepicker-popup did not allow for either date type, but now the validation is firing.  LOL!  Thanks!